# Implement an SPA with IFrames, but with Single Sign-on

Tags: oauth2, openid-connect, sso, single-page-app, single-sign-on

I want to build an SPA with ASP.NET Core (Blazor server side) which some IFrames redirecting to other applications. In this example I have f.e. the SPA, [Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/) to show graphs and [Node-Red](https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/oauth), but there could be more in the future. To create a simple user flow I want the user to login only once in my SPA and then have access to Node-Red and Grafana. Also I want to implement multi-tenancy for all those applications.

Flow: User1 logs in SPA and see's the graphs in Grafana for his/her organization. User2 logs in but sees different graphs for the other organization.

I just started with using OAuth2/OpenID Connect. For that I am using currently [Ory's Hydra](https://github.com/ory/hydra). I managed to get the login process working with ASP.NET Core and Hydra OpenID Connect. I don't want to go too technical, as I post this here on security SE and I am not quite sure, if this is the right direction I am heading. But just so you know my current process: I created an [IFrame with sandbox configs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857281/iframe-wont-respect-login-cookies)  within my SPA, set the cookies to `SameSite=None`, updated the Grafana config to use the same client id as my SPA and hoped that Grafana would magically log in (spoiler: it doesn't)

I understand that this could be a security risk and I read a lot of articles explaining why IFrame and OAuth2 are not the best friends. So currently I am stuck.

So my question is: **What is the best and securest way to implement a SPA with single sign up and single sign on and where should I start**? I would love to use OpenID Connect as I always read on this very side: "Never roll your own security implementation!" and it's a standard a lot of applications have already built in, but I am open minded for better calls. And should I use IFrames at all? Or are there better options?